# python-request module throwing EndPointConnectionError intermittently when it is used along with asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-asyncio

I am trying to make a post call to an external api from my method,

```
async def post(self, request, **args):

        loop = app.loop # Event loop

        #Service proxy is basically a wrapper on top of request library

        proxy = ServiceProxy(url, port=HTTPS_PORT,
                            context_path="/", scheme=SCHEME_HTTPS,
                            verify_host=False, proxies=await 
                            get_proxies()) # get_proxies=>system_proxy

        req = partial(proxy.post, url, headers=headers,
                           payload=data_json)

        return await loop.run_in_executor(None, req)
    except ExternalServiceException as e:
        logger.error(e.inner_response.text)
        return e.inner_response
```

2 out of 5 times the method fails with `EndpointConnectionError` but if I stop and start the service it works absolutely fine, I am not able to find the root cause,

Also addding loggers in the code seem to reduce the occurrence of the error,

At the outlook asyncio seem to be causing the issue here,
But I am not able to figure out the solution,
can someone point out the exact issue / suggest a solution?

Comment: I don't follow why `aiohttp` is tagged?

Comment: @sorry Andrew, i was working on aiohttp, guess the muscle memory kicked in and added it, sorry